# How to connect to PostgreSQL database with Laravel Homestead?

Tags: laravel-5, homestead

I have updated the DB connection in my **.env** file to change the default mysql database to use PostgreSQL DB. But I don't know how to proceed with this.

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
```

For example, we use

```
mysql -uhomestead -psecret <DB Name>
```

to connect to our database. By using psql, how to connect to DB?

Comment: `psql -Uhomestead <DB Name>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one,

```
psql -U homestead -h localhost <DB Name>
```

After that, it will ask for password, enter secret. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to postgress via `ssh` using `psql` i do:

```
psql -U homestead -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 myappdb

# this will ask for a password
# the default in homestead is secret
```